# Copying attachments to new feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, fields-attributes, attachments

I'm trying to bring attachments from a feature class to a new feature class (using all the same attributes). My problem with the old feature class is I've had to reorder the fields. I have figured out how to reorder my fields list (used a "ReorderFields" python script). I then loaded the old feature class into the new one. Problem I am running into is the GlobalID is different from the old feature class to the new and the attachments on the old feature class run on those GlobalIDs...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Maybe reorder my original feature class without having to recreate a whole new one?

Or bring over the GlobalIDs to the new one so it can connect that way?

Comment: generate a number (1,2,3,n) in a value field and do the same on you destination data and join that.

Comment: Not sure how you're saying to do that.. I included the names of the polygons but still no luck. Attachments are still linked to the GlobalID

Comment: join both datasets together then export as one.

Answer (score 2):

Check this page: 
http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011569

"Upgrade to ArcGIS for Desktop 10.5, or use ArcGIS Pro 1.3. A new environment, Maintain Attachments, has been implemented in some Conversion and Data Management tools in ArcGIS for Desktop"

I just tried the append tool in Pro and it works great!